# Has there been any big collisions with ice bergs after Titantic or during the Age of Sail?

Tags: age-of-sail, titanic

Has there been any big collisions with ice bergs after Titantic or during the Age of Sail? What happened? Especially during WW2, wasn't there a lot of naval moments in the Arctic?

Comment: What do you consider to be a 'big' collision?

Comment: Fishing boats are too small. Ships that are maybe 50-100 m long and with 100+ people onboard. Give or take. Advanced instruments for its epoch.

Comment: Wikipedia has a [list of ships that were sunk by icebergs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ships_sunk_by_icebergs).

Answer (score 2):

No. The Titanic disaster is quite unique. Sailing through iceberg infested waters was rare during the age of sail, for several reasons:

1. Mass passenger transport ships didn't exist. Ships carried *some*
   passengers, but weren't designed as passenger ships. Therefore the
   loss of life could be substantial, but nowhere near that of the
   Titanic.
2. Why would someone take a dangerous non-profitable route to the Americas?
3. Icebergs can sink relatively slow moving ships as well, but that risk is
   much smaller than a ship running at full speed under steam.
4. Whalers cruised far to the north, but they were accustomed to the weather, dangers and the icebergs. If they sank, the loss of life wasn't as horrendous as when the Titanic went down. I am certain some whalers did sink after hitting an iceberg, but ships sink all the time. It's not something that would be remembered today.

> Especially during WW2, wasn't there a lot of naval moments in the Arctic?

Yes, there was. Only icebergs were the least of their problems. [*Focke Wulf "Condors"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focke-Wulf_Fw_200_Condor), U-Boats and [German surface warships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_battleship_Scharnhorst) were a far greater threat, not to mention the appalling weather. The ships kept a very vigilant lookout for any danger. Icebergs being just one of them, and a minor one at that.

Comment: And, probably, hiding behind icebergs may have been quite handy...

Comment: @Jos You imply that sailing in the arctic in WWII was only dangerous for allied ships.  I am sure the allies made efforts to make it dangerous for Axis ships as well.

Comment: @MAGolding I don't infer anything. I didn't mention allied war efforts in the Arctic. That's not the same. ;-)